# i am not getting to increment max value from database above 10 in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$con=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      $d=mysql_select_db("laabhaa_crm",$con);

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(LT_8690) 
FROM lead") or die(mysql_error());

 if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 $a=$row['MAX(LT_8690)']+1;

  ?> 
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="LT" style="width:16px;"/>/
                    <input name="LT_8690" type="text" value="<?php echo $a;?>" readonly="readonly" id="" style="width:60px;">

                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: What is this... Post your query as well

Comment: The query is posted. Read it again Sunil.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: i am not getting to increment  $a value after 10 .when i run my program then its doesnt works

Answer (score 1):

Your query is this:

```
SELECT MAX(LT_8690) 
FROM lead
```

The way you're trying to access that field is like this:

```
$row['MAX(LT_8690)']
```

This is incorrect. The column's name is not `MAX(LT_8690)`. The column doesn't have a name. Let's give it one, as such:

```
SELECT MAX(LT_8690) AS 'maxLt8690'
FROM lead

$row['maxLt8690']
```

I like this option because I get to be specific with names. This makes my code more readable, which helps me when I have to go back and update it.

Comment: but my column's name is LT_8690.so what i do .

Comment: Your column is indeed named `LT_8690`. However, the column returned by `MAX(*)` does not have a name. You cannot access it using `MAX(LT_8690)` in PHP, because that is not the name of the field. The field has no name by default. You can alternatively access by index, but it's more convenient to access by name.

Comment: so i want to access that column value maximam value so what will be query?

Comment: Read my answer. The query is there.

Comment: where is the answer of my question?

Comment: Bottom of the post. You don't see the query...?

Comment: <?php
$con=  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      $d=mysql_select_db("matrimonial",$con);
   
   
echo "<table>";

$sql="select img_path from matri where user_na='suresh'";


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))

Comment: echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $row["img_path"];?>" height="100" width="100><?php echo "</td>";
}

echo "</table>";

Comment: how to diplay image in php